# How to change categorical column values?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-cleaning

In my data frame, I have column 'countries', I am trying to change that column values into 'developed countries' and 'developing countries'. My data frame is as following:

```
   countries age gender
1  India     21  Male
2  China     22  Female
3  USA       23  Male
4  UK        25  Male
```

I have following two arrays:

```
developed = ['USA','UK']
developing = ['India', 'China']
```

I want to convert array into following data frame:

```
   countries    age gender
1  developing   21  Male
2  developing   22  Female
3  developed    23  Male
4  developed    25  Male
```

I tried following code, but I got 'SettingWithCopyWarning' error:

```
df[df['countries'].isin(developed)]['countries'] = 'developed'
```

I tried following code, but I got 'SettingWithCopyWarning' error and my jupyter notebook got hanged:

```
for i, x in enumerate(df['countries']):
    if x in developed:
        df['countries'][i] = 'developed'
```

Is their alternative way to change column categories??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np 
df['countries']=np.where(df['countries'].isin(developed),'developed','developing')
print(df)

    countries  age  gender
1  developing   21    Male
2  developing   22  Female
3   developed   23    Male
4   developed   25    Male
```

Also you can use [DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
c=df['countries'].isin(developed)
df.loc[c,'countries']='developed'
df.loc[~c,'countries']='developing'
print(df)


   countries  age  gender
1  developing   21    Male
2  developing   22  Female
3   developed   23    Male
4   developed   25    Male
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try implementing a replace function, it wouldn't give an error.

```
Updated_DataSet1 = data_set.replace("India", "Developing")
Updated_DataSet2 = Updated_DataSet1.replace("China","Developing")
```